# How to initialize a three dimensional array in CPLEX?

Tags: arrays, error-handling, initialization, cplex, ibm-ilog-opl

> int t=4;  int b=3;  int e=5; range time =1..t;  range bus=1..b; range
> ev=1..e; float soci[ev][bus][time]=[[[0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]]
> [[0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]]
> [ [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]]
> [ [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]]
> [ [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
> [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]]];

I was trying to initialize a three dimensional array in this manner . But here an error is showing unexpected '[' expecting ']'.How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int t=4; int b=3; int e=5; range time =1..t; range bus=1..b; 

range ev=1..e; 

float soci[ev][bus][time]=
[[[0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]] ,[[0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
 [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]] ,[ [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7],
  [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]] ,[ [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]] ,
  [ [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7]]];
  
  execute
  {
    writeln(soci);
  }
```

works fine. You were missing some commas.